# Поставить галочку "Автоматическое определение параметров"

Tags: c#

Требуется winservice, который будет каждые 10 сек проверять **в какой он подсети и в зависимости от этого ставить или убирать галку «Автоматическое определение параметров (прокси)»** в IE (способ описан ниже).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

С вин-сервисом все понятно,  я не могу понять как получить список имеющихся подсетей, и проставить ту галочку. на картинке 3 ВПНа, значит, как я понимаю подсети 3. В зависимости от того, где будет ноутбук находиться, винсервис будет определять активную подсеть и проставлять ту галочку. Я так понимаю, он должен работать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста как мне подступиться к этой задачей, нету идей.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4283310/3061227